# .NET Core testing output format

Tags: .net, jenkins, continuous-integration, nunit, .net-core

In order to integrate unit testing into my [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)/[CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) build pipeline, I need to run tests via the command line and output them in a format that Jenkins can read.

Recently, there was a significant change to .NET Core where `project.json` and `.xproj` files have been converted into the `.csproj` format. This change broke my previous integration with NUnit 3.

As of writing, NUnit does not support .NET Core v1.0.3.

Is there a `dotnet test` setting that will enable me to output the results in a Jenkins readable format (e.g. xUnit, NUnit, or JUnit)?

Comment: Rewrite the tests with xUnit?

Comment: Legacy software tests were written in NUnit. Easier for devs to maintain a single Testing Framework.
Also, I'm unsure if xUnit is supported natively with Resharper.

Comment: R# xUnit support is becoming better and better and it is almost good for .net core. The biggest problem I faced this month is `Trait` attribute is not discovered well. I've already reported the bug to R# team.

Comment: just in case: if you need line-by-line output inside console, then `dotnet test --logger:"console;verbosity=detailed"` - can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.8.0-alpha1 has been released by the NUnit folks which supports Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core. [NuGet link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.8.0-alpha1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dotnet test --logger trx` (or if you only use Visual Studio 2017 MSBuild: `msbuild /t:VSTest /p:VSTestLogger=trx`) to get the VSTest .trx format which has a lot of CI support.

If you used xUnit, the upcoming 2.3 version will feature a `dotnet xunit` command that can output xUnit XML files directly. See *[Getting Started with xUnit.net](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html)*.